# Are there examples of non-trivial structures, where associativity plus commutativity does not lead to a "natural" distributivity law?

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory

I'm currently watching Michael Penn doing a grounds up, essentially from bare set theory, to addition and multiplication on natural numbers. This second video is on multiplication. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynIee3OvZ5A

Comment: Endomorphism rings come equipped with a distributive law. For the integers that's multiplication but all abelian groups have an endomorphism ring associated with it. So there is always a natural distributive structure here.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Wait, are there rings which have distributivity without assoc + comm? Thanks for replying

Comment: Rings are associative and commutative under addition and multiplication is associative. They're not required to be commutative under multiplication though such as the endomorphism rings of a vector space with respect to its addition operation.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks, that helps

Comment: Please make the bodies of your MSE questions self-contained. Don't rely on the title for important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lattices provide one example. In a lattice, there are two binary operations, $\land$ and $\lor$. They are both associative and commutative. But they can violate the distributive law
$$ x \land (y \lor z) = (x \land y) \lor (x \land z)$$
A theorem of Birkhoff provides a simple characterization of when a lattice is nondistributive: it must contain a copy of one of two small lattices known as $M_3$ (the *diamond*) and $N_5$ (the *pentagon*).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I know about lattice theory. Accepting your answer